# Is there any Emmet-like plugin for Eclipse 2020-06 to use with HTML templates?

Tags: html, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, emmet

Does anyone know if there is a plugin that allows you to quickly edit HTML in Eclipse IDE 2020-06 like Emmet did? This plugin (`https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/emmet`) is not compatible with this version of Eclipse.

It allows you to do things like typing:

```
p#myid.form-control.foo
```

and after pressing TAB, this would become:

```
<p id="myid" class="form-control foo"></p>
```

Comment: Looks like the underlying site at http://download.emmet.io/eclipse/updates/ is broken or misconfigured, too.